# Triple curl of vector field

Tags: calculus, vector-fields

I'm having trouble understanding what this triple curl is:

$$ \boldsymbol \nabla \times \boldsymbol \nabla \times \boldsymbol \nabla \times \mathrm{A} =\quad ?$$

where $\mathrm{A}$ is a vector field. In component form I wrote:

$$ \alpha_i =(\boldsymbol \nabla \times \vec{\mathrm{A}})_i = \epsilon_{ijk} \partial_j \mathrm{A}_k $$

Then:

$$ \beta_m= (\boldsymbol \nabla \times \boldsymbol \nabla \times \vec{\mathrm{A}})_m = \epsilon_{mni} \partial_n \alpha_i = (\delta_{jm} \delta_{kn} - \delta_{jn} \delta_{km}) \partial_n \partial_j \mathrm{A}_k $$

and finally:

$$ (\boldsymbol \nabla \times \vec{\beta} )_a = \epsilon_{abm} \partial_b \beta_m = \epsilon_{abm} \partial_b ( (\delta_{jm} \delta_{kn} - \delta_{jn} \delta_{km}) \partial_n \partial_j \mathrm{A}_k  ) $$

$$ (\boldsymbol \nabla \times \vec{\beta} )_a = \epsilon_{abm} (\delta_{jm} \delta_{kn} - \delta_{jn} \delta_{km})\partial_b ( \partial_n \partial_j \mathrm{A}_k  ) $$

$$ ( \boldsymbol \nabla \times \vec{\beta})_a = \epsilon_{abm} (\delta_{jm} \delta_{kn} )\partial_b (\partial_n \partial_j \textrm{A}_k ) - \epsilon_{abm} ( \delta_{jn} \delta_{km})\partial_b  (\partial_n \partial_j \mathrm{A}_k ) $$

$$ ( \boldsymbol \nabla \times \vec{\beta})_a = \epsilon_{abj} \partial_b ( \partial_k \partial_j \textrm{A}_k  ) - \epsilon_{abk} \partial_b  (  \partial_j \partial_j \mathrm{A}_k  ) $$

I see a Laplacian on the last term, but don't know what to do from here, as in, how is the initial expression represented in terms of divergence, curl, Laplacian and gradient. How do I finish this?

I am aware of the identity:

$$ \boldsymbol \nabla \times \boldsymbol \nabla \times \mathbf{A}= \boldsymbol \nabla(\boldsymbol \nabla \cdot \mathbf{A}) - \nabla^2 \mathbf{A}$$

and I could just apply the curl to both terms, but isnt there another way to represent this?

Comment: Use [$\varepsilon-\delta$ identity](https://webhome.phy.duke.edu/~rgb/Class/Electrodynamics/Electrodynamics/node21.html) : $\varepsilon_{ijk}\varepsilon_{imn}=\delta_{jm}\delta_{kn} - \delta_{jn}\delta_{km}$

Comment: I don't understand your problem. If you do the calculation you get a 3 vector with each component having 3 plus terms and 3 minus terms each of which are 3rd order partial derivatives. You can write it out explicitly. What am I missing?

Comment: Perhaps I wasn´t explicit enough, I was trying to find another expression for this triple curl other then just applying the curl to the identity mentioned above.